# Java; null pointer on newly created array with user-defined length

Tags: java

So, right after the public class declaration, I've declared an array as follows:

```
public String[] accept;
```

From here then, I'm looking to take user input to see how long this array should be - and following this, we'd enter into a loop to populate the array with Strings. I put the following into a method;

```
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
wcount = scanner.nextInt();
//create the array.
String accept[] = new String[wcount];
}
System.out.println(accept.length);
```

But unfortunately, no nice. Java returns with;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Obviously, attempting to go straight into a for loop to populate the array, will also give the same results. At first glance, I'm assuming this has something to do with it being initialised as a public array outside of the method itself - but I'm honestly not too sure. Can anyone lend a hand on this?

Comment: please, show where you got `NullPointerException`?

Comment: I assume this is homework, but still, the obligatory: prefer ArrayList instead of array for almost every use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring a new array in your if block, which is hiding your previously declared array. When the block exits, the variable goes out of scope and you get an NPE attempting to access the (unchanged) instance variable. Change your code to actually initialize your instance variable like so:

```
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    wcount = scanner.nextInt();

    //create the array.
    accept = new String[wcount];
}
System.out.println(accept.length);
```

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for that! 

This has actually solved the immediate error - but now the problem is, that whenever I attempt to call the array outside of it's object, it returns back with a null pointer exception. for example; in my main method, I am creating a seperate object on the class itself; however, whenever I refer to it via object.accept, it's throwing back a null pointer exception. Any ideas?

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept my answer if it helped. Please post your new issue as a separate question, complete with code snippets.

Comment: Forgot to throw in a this. on the array inside the object - thank you! Answer accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

You are recreating a new `accept []` as local variable. Change your loop as below

```
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
  wcount = scanner.nextInt();
  //create the array.
  accept = new String[wcount];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `String accept[]` to just `accept` within the `if` statement, you are redeclaring a new one within that scope, leaving the old one `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String accept[] = new String[wcount];
```

declares a variable, and stores the reference to the new string array into it.

You probably want to use the previously declared variable instead. To do that, simply use assignment expression directly:

```
accept = new String[wcount];
```