# Does the length of a newly instantiated array resolve to 0 or null?

Tags: c#, arrays

HOMEWORK: I'm getting and index out-of-bounds on the following code. It's a hangman game, and I'm keeping track of the letters I've guessed in a `char` array.

Here's the assumptions I made:

1. In the calling method, I have an unpopulated array (`char[] displayGuesses = new char[26];`) passing to the method below as the `char[] usedLetters` parameter.
2. The first iteration of the letter-guessing, the array will be empty.
3. It's length will be 0.
4. I populate `usedLetters[0]` with the `letterGuessed` parameter.
5. The next time I guess, length of the array will be 1, so `usedLetters[1]` gets populated...and so on.

   ```
   public char[] trackUsedLetters(char letterGuessed, char[] usedLetters)
   {
       int letterIndex = usedLetters.Length;
       usedLetters[letterIndex] = letterGuessed;  
       return usedLetters;
   }
   ```

There's a couple things I think may be going on.

1. When I try to get the length of `usedLetters` on the first run, the empty array does
   NOT return zero, but null. Boom. Out-of-bounds.
2. There's some issue with passing a blank array defined with 26
   members...? But I'm not sure what that issue would even BE, so I have no idea what to google that will yield relevant results.
3. I may have a scope issue; I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553014/java-null-pointer-on-newly-created-array-with-user-defined-length) to a similar
   question for Java, though using a `for` loop. I don't *quite* get
   what the Java user was going for, but some of the problems sounded
   familiar.

I need a second pair of eyes to look at this and point me in the right direction for solving this.

Comment: `usedLetters[letterIndex]` will always throw an exception since arrays are 0 based. In other words, valid indices are from 0 to n-1 if n is the length of the array.

Comment: How is the array "empty" when you are passing in displayGuesses, which is of length 26?  Please show more complete code, including the caller to the function, etc.

Comment: @oldProgrammer - I'm whipping up more complete code right now...but. If I just have the line `char[] displayGuesses = new char[26];` what does it get populated WITH? Brand new array, 26 "slots" if you will, no data elements assigned to any of those  26 slots. That's what I mean when I say empty. Is there actually some value in there when the array is defined?

Comment: How could the length resolve to null? It's an `int`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I didn't think it would. Per my assumptions listed in my question, I assumed that an "empty" array would have a length of zero, and I could populate `array[0]` using the integer variable as the slot number of the array. This of course would only work the first time, but the second time I called the method, with a length of 1, I'd be looking to populate `array[1]`...can you see where I was going with that? That's why I'm trying to understand why I'm getting an out-of-bounds error.

Comment: So, why does your title talk about `null`? And, if the array is empty, then it has _no_ elements, and using `array[0]` will get you an index out of range error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want `List<char>` that can grow (with `Add`) method.

Arrays have fixed size and following code (that you have in sample) will **always** throw out of range exception because you are accessing element past last element in array.

```
usedLetters[usedLetters.Length] = 'c';
```

More details on array length:

```
// newArray - array of 0 chars. newArray.Length is 0
var newArray = new char[0]; 

// nullArray not created, nullArray.Length will throw NullReferenceExcetption
char[] nullArray = null; 

// defaultArray = array of 26 characters, each value 0.
// defaultArray.Length is 26;
char[] defaultArray = new char[26];
```

Comment: If we weren't being forced to use arrays in class this week, I would use `List<char>` and the `ADD` method.  :)  So it sounds like a newly defined array would NOT pass a value of 0 for its length? My hope was I could use an integer variable from `array.length` to populate my next slot in the array. The first time, with a length of 0, I could reference `array[0]`, because the NEW array was of 0 length. Then, with a value in `array[0]`, the length would resolve to 1...and I could populate `array[1]`. I guess that's not how it works, though....

Comment: @dwwilson66, you are right - length of array is fixed from the moment of creation and can't be changed. Same variable can point to another array of different length where you can copy an old array (that how List is implemented - it copies internal array into new one that is bigger size when it needs to grow).

Comment: // defaultArray = array of 26 characters, each value 0.
char[] defaultArray = new char[26];  is what I was missing. your comments that it's a 26-length array makes sense, thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 4):

According to the c# specification: (emphasis mine)

> **1.8 Arrays**
>
> Array types are reference types, and the declaration of an array variable simply sets aside space for a reference to an array instance. **Actual array instances are created dynamically at run-time using the new operator. The new operation specifies the length of the new array instance, which is then fixed for the lifetime of the instance**. The indices of the elements of an array range from 0 to Length - 1. **The new operator automatically initializes the elements of an array to their default value**, which, for example, is zero for all numeric types and null for all reference types.

[Default Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which gives the char data type default as '\0'

Answer (score 0):

When you define a new array, but don't manually initialize the items inside of it, it will automatically be initialized with the default values for whatever type the array contains. In your case, you're creating a character array. The default value for a char is '\0', or the null character.

This means that the array is never truly "empty." If you define an array with 26 slots, it will always have that length, unless you make a new array.